# Push log files to AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, log-files, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a log file (example: apilog.txt) inside my docker container running in an EC2 instance.

**I need to push the content in that file to AWS Cloudwatch log groups.**

How can I achieve this task .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - **[Use ECS instead of EC2+docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html)**. ECS is the same thing (EC2+docker) but better because it's integrated with other AWS services like CloudWatch and the container logs are automatically fed into CloudWatch Logs.

Option 2 - Use **[CloudWatch Logs logging agent in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)**

Option 3 - Use **[standalone CloudWatch Logs Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)** that can read log files and feed them to CloudWatch.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hello MLu, I am actually using ECS only, I am pushing docker logs to Cloud watch but I need to push a file that is inside the container, not the container logs,